# SignalR client method is not executing everytime while displaying a stream of messages.But it is working with debugger, why?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

The client method DisplayMessage is not executing everytime. I need to display a stream of message. But when I put debugger in the client code, it executes everytime.Here is my client code.

```
chat.client.displayMessage = function (data) {                
        // Html encode display data 

        debugger;

        var encodedData = $('<div />').text(data.GPSPosition).html();
        var data = encodedData.split("\n");
        var varlat = data[0].replace("Latitude:","").trim();
        var varlong = data[1].replace("Longitude:", "").trim();
        ShowInGoogleMap(varlat, varlong);
      };
```

how can i display a stream of messages? Why it is only working with debugger?

Here is my server code. I am calling client method from a class outside the hub class.

```
     IHubContext hubContext =    GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AzureGuidanceEventHubReceiver>();                    
     hubContext.Clients.All.DisplayMessage(newData);
```

Comment: What does the `ShowInGoogleMap` function do? I doubt the issue might be with that function. Have you tried commenting it out?

Comment: No...thats not depend on that. Initially it was like                                      var encodedData = $('<div />').text(data.GPSPosition).html();
$('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedData + '</li>');                             It is also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue in your code because your method parameter has the same name as a local variable (data). Modify the name of your local variable and it should be ok. In debug mode, the value of data is not overwritten.

Comment: chat.client.displayMessage = function (data) {                
  var encodedData = $('<div />').text(data.GPSPosition).html();
   $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedData + '</li>');
                };
        This code is also having the problem.